# How to define a number of properties at once on a flavor level

Tags: java, android, android-flavors

So I have a three-option menu, which can show (on a flavor level) either one of the options (no matter which), two of the options, three of them or none. What is the best way to set a property in which I can define the visible options for each flavor? I already put `boolean` flags for each option, but later on more options might be needed and I'll end up having a lot of flags. This made me think that there might be a better approach here. Something like

```
options.setOptionOne(true);
options.setOptionTwo(false);
options.setOptionThree(true);
```

But if I do it this way in any custom `Class`, how am I supposed to get `options` for each flavor?

#### Edit:

Thanks to [@deHaar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1712135/dehaar), who found out that there is a way to programmatically check which flavor is running and by this to set the proper properties at once.

```
if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("flavorOne")) {
    ...
}
else if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("flavorTwo")) {
    ...
}
```

This is the most clean solution as of now. If someone else knows a better, more clean approach I'd love to have a look at it!

Comment: Where is this property supposed to be located? In a class? Are the options all in a single class? Could you please post more code, especially one which touches these options?

Comment: @deHaar The code I posted is pseudo code. What I've done for now is set a flag for each flavor: in main/properties.xml set everything to false and then set the flags to true in the necessary flavors (in /flavorOne/properties.xml for example). I want to know if there is a way to do this without flags, but in a Class instead, and still affect every flavor differently, according to the values of its properties.

Comment: So flavors are more than 2 different values (not a `boolean`)? If yes, you could use some `enum`…
Please show some real code including flavor and its options.

Comment: @deHaar Flavors in Android are different versions of the main application. Let's say you have a paid application and you want to make a free version of it. For that purpose you create a new flavor of your main app, where you change a bit of the views and cut some of the functionality, so the users can have a basic idea of your app and decide if they want to buy the full version. I can't really post a code of a flavor, since it can contain a lot of classes and their corresponding views. I hope you now understand my question better :)

Comment: OK, very good explanation in your last comment ;-) Thanks!
Configuring that will probably need some application config file that holds/sets values based on the flavor. Maybe an asset or a resource, but could be any custom file. You could define different flavor options there and switch based on the application flavor.

Comment: @deHaar This is exactly what I'm doing. Currently all the flags are put in the properties.xml, which can be different file for each flavor. Now I'm trying to do that from a `Class`, but I'm not sure how to do it properly :)

Comment: How do you determine which flavor is chosen on application start?

Comment: @deHaar You declare new flavors in the build.gradle file of your project, and from the `Build Variants` menu you choose the flavor you want to build. This creates a build with all the classes, images and views of the selected flavor.

Comment: From what I understand from the documentation, you're doing exactly as intended. Which advantages do you expect from flavors in the code? A direct flavor switch at runtime?

Comment: I expect to be able to change more than one property of a said flavor at once without the need of using many flags. I suppose that can happen with a custom `Class`, but since I haven't done this before and what I tried doesn't work I'm asking if it's actually possible to achieve something like this.

Comment: Well, check out the following link and look for the `BuildConfig` class:
https://android.jlelse.eu/android-build-variants-6880a07abf0

Comment: @deHaar This is what I was looking for. I'll see what I can make out of this now. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172251/discussion-between-dehaar-and-noterezeck).